# IntelliJ not creating/importing new Play Framework project correctly

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

*note: I recently jumped into Play Framework, so I am still learning all about it*

I am trying to create a simple Webapp using the Play Framework.\

**(edit) Software Versions:**

- Arch Linux: 4.11.7-1-ARCH x64
- Oracle Java JDK: 1.8.0_131
- IntelliJ Scala plugin: 2017.1.19 (latest)
- SBT: 0.13.13 (latest)
- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.4
- Play Framework: 2.6.1

**What I did:**

I followed [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html) tutorial from the Jetbrains site to start a Play Framework project. I followed the instructions exactly.

1. I installed the Scala plugin
2. Created new project > Scala > Play 2.x (shown in the image is Scala, Dotty, SBT, Activator, Play 2.x. My options were SBT, IDEA, Activator, Play 2.x)
3. Project details page looked similar, using `Scala 2.11` and `Play 2.6.1` and `Java JDK 1.8.0_131`

**Problem:**

4. Clicked finish and I expected to see the next image with the project directory structure shown. All that was shown is 3 Entries: `.gitignore` file, `build` file and External Libraries

Since something had gone wrong, I decided to import the project, when doing so, by selecting `SBT` project model I get an import error:

**Importing error:**

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)
at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)
at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)
at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
a
t xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/TrackLevel
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Invalid response.</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="file:/home/cybex/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log">file:/home/cybex/.IntelliJIdea2017.1/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

I have found none with the same issue.

**What I tried:**

I searched and found a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727647/sbt-fails-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-sbt-consoleout), simply mentioning to delete the `~/.sbt` and `~/.ivy2` folders. I did so, but it solved nothing.

I proceeded to reimport the same project, this time it redownloaded the `sbt` and `ivy` packages and showed the folder/project structure within IntelliJ's project window

When opening the `sbt` menu/tool and importing/refreshing all projects, the above shown importing error is printed again.

**Question:**

What is causing this, a missing library, a missing checkbox while importing?

**Update:**

I managed to get a project working by using the method described under [PlayFramework 2.6.1 New application](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/NewApplication#Create-a-new-application-using-SBT).

1. I fired up a terminal, browsed to location of where my project needs to be, ran `sbt new playframework/play-java-seed.g8`, when prompted I entered the project name, organization, scala version, etc.
2. I then opened intellij, imported this project (project name, inside where I ran the `sbt new ...` command), using SBT project model. After downloading and checking dependancies, it showed the project structure, although missing a few folders like `sbt-build` directory (seen this in example play project).

Opening the SBT Project toolbar, and clicking refresh, it has successfully imported all project and they were visible as expected.

**Conclusion:**

The documentation on `Jetbrains IntelliJ` website may be inaccurate, since my scala version was the same. Only difference was Java JDK version, I believe this needs to be confirmed.

Comment: Which sbt version are you using?

Comment: @Salem sbt 0.13.13

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2`.

But it doesn't happen with `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1`.

I think you'd better update `IntelliJ IDEA`, and retry.