# Java AWT in scala: (AWT-EventQueue-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, awt

I'm trying to use java awt in scala to make a simple desktop application. I have been working on it for some days without any problem, until I didn't touch it for 2 days and when I came back, I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception. It was working fine before, but now even the simplest of code gives me this error.

https://github.com/aganm/NoClassDefFoundError

> Main.scala

```
import java.awt.{EventQueue}

class Bar(val bar: Int) {
}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    EventQueue.invokeLater(() => {
      val b = new Bar(20)
      println(b.bar)
    });

  }

}
```

I run it with sbt

```
sbt run
```

It compiles, but I get this exception

```
[error] (AWT-EventQueue-0) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Bar
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Bar
[error]         at Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Main.scala:11)
[error]         at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
[error] oats / Cat java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
[error]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Bar
[error]         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]         at Main$.$anonfun$main$1(Main.scala:11)
[error]         at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
[error]         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[error]         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
[error]         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
[error]         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Compile / bgRun for the full output
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sbt fails with java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/ConsoleOut$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727647/sbt-fails-with-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-sbt-consoleout)

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw It looks like the same error, but none of the proposed solutions work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect a SBT bug. I can reproduce the issue with SBT 1.3.0, but not with SBT 1.2.8. Also I do not reproduce the issue when I add `fork := true` into the `build.sbt` file even when using SBT 1.3.0. You can use any of those options as a workaround.

I have reported the issue as [Strange NoClassDefFoundError error with SBT 1.3.0](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5088) and it is now fixed in SBT 1.3.2.

The 1.3.0 new functionality seems to be [In process class loading](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/In-Process-Classloaders.html) - however none of the values described seems to fix the issue, therefore I am not sure if it really related.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact related to an issue of sbt 1.3.0's stricter ClassLoader and thread management during `run` task, which should be fixed in the next patch release.

In the meantime however, forking does work:

```scala
Compile/ run / fork := true
```

Here's the output:

```
sbt:NoClassDefFoundError> run
[info] running (fork) Main
[info] 20
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 17, 2019 11:29:04 AM
```

I think the related bug is [[1.3.0] not terminating ActorSystem leads to `NoClassDefFoundError` at the end of `run` as sbt cleans up the ClassLoader #5075](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/5075). In your case, `EventDispatchThread` keeps running even after `Main.main` is exited. sbt cleans after the `run` and removes the ClassLoader (which has your classes in it), so when `EventDispatchThread` runs it can no longer find your classes.

[Close in-process classloader only once run has completed #5081](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/5081), hopefully fixes this issue.