# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after installing Visual GC inside Java VisualVM

Tags: java, scala, jvisualvm

Im using IntelliJ with Java 8 and scala plugin. My code was running fine just with some input I got GC error. So I wanted to use Java VisualVM with Visual GC error. After I installed the plugin I can't run my code due to

```
Internal error: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/internal/Types$$Lambda$111
```

(I can send more lines of that error)

Comment: Does it happen on any code? Could you provide a bit more information about your code&setup?

Comment: Now it happens at all codes (I have and they were running fine before). It's basically algorithm to  find "the best" way from the root to a leaf in a tree. I guess that the Vector where I save vertices to be searched was getting to big with some inputs thatś why I had the GC error. I don t know what setup info is relevant since it just stopped working when I installed the plugin (uninstalling doesn t help)

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960185/java-awt-in-scala-awt-eventqueue-0-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror?noredirect=1#comment102333407_57960185

Comment: I don't think so. And in Event Log it shows: Scala Compile Server
   Profiler Agent Warning: JVMTI classLoadHook: class name is null.
   Profiler Agent Warning: JVMTI classLoadHook: class name is null.